# Hover Animation not behaving properly in CSS

Tags: html, css

Inisde this div .total I am trying to do this hover animation where the opacity and width changes when I hover one either of the two elements. the change in width is smooth when I hover in the left element but it is practically non existent when I hover in the right element.

codepen : https://codepen.io/aronnora/pen/eYNazyV

html

```
<div class="total">
    <div class="one">
      <img src="liquid-immersed-distribution-transformers-768x784.png" alt="kakashi" class="Kakashi" height="300rem"></img>

      <div class="downtextone">
  時メユ郎
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <img src="transtech-2.png" alt="madara" class="Madara" height="300rem"></img>
      <div class="downtexttwo">
        時メユ
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.total:hover > div{
  opacity: 0;
}
.total:hover > div:hover{
  z-index: 20;
  opacity: 1;
  width:90rem;
}
.total:hover > :not(.div:hover){
  width:0;
}
.one:hover > .downtextone{
  text-align: center;
  opacity:1;
}
.two:hover > .downtexttwo{
  text-align: center;
  width:90rem;
  opacity:1;
}
.one:hover > .Kakashi{
  padding-left: 33rem;
}
.two:hover > .Madara{
}

.two:hover{
  height:auto;
  width:90rem;
}
```

Comment: In the future, please eliminate all unrelated markup and CSS from your demo. It adds to the difficulty of troubleshooting. Also, nested `:hover` pseudo-classes usually aren't a good idea. For one thing, they're redundant. For another, it confuses your style rules.

Comment: Here's a simplified demo: https://codepen.io/isherwood-the-styleful/pen/zYGQoyz

Answer (score 0):

I used some absolute positioning to solve it.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.left:hover {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: grey;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.right:hover {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

https://codepen.io/camwes89/pen/WNvBomb